# When we need to serialize an exception

Tags: java, exceptions, serialization

I have been developing in Java since 8 months, and I didn't face a case where I went to serialize an exception, I'm asking because I saw the `serialVersionUID` and how Eclipse advise to add it explicitly in the Exception class that you define. So, I think that every(or the majority) exception is being serialized and I don't know that, maybe because the framework or the language itself is handling this issue.

I know that serialization is needed when you need to transfer the object through the network or when you need to store it, and I get the idea that we actually serialize the exception when we save the logs/exception backtrace into for example, `catalina.out` file, am I correct? and what other use cases that may need to serialize the exception?

Comment: Sounds like you got it right.  You serialize exceptions for the same reasons you serialize any other object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But why Eclipse is focusing on setting `serialVersionUID`  for exception classes more than other classes? I understand that `serialVersionUID ` is more related to network rather than storing, and I don't see in which case we want to transfer an exception through the network.

Comment: Eclipse enforces setting `serialVersionUID` in all classes implementing the Serializable interface. Throwable implements Serializable, and so your subclass inherits that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to serialize a class, [it needs a serialVersionID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285809).

Your exception classes [should always be serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7683796/102937).  You have no idea where the exception might be used, and if it gets marshaled across an app domain, you may lose debugging information or even lose the entire exception altogether.  Exceptions are intended to be usable *anywhere,* and if they're not serializable, you can't use them across app domains.

[The same principles also apply to C# exceptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066701/why-should-i-always-make-my-exceptions-serializable-net)